# docker networking in Multi host in same network

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have two ubuntu os in my system . I install docker in both ubuntu and create a containers in both the dockers and i need to communicate with the networks ...

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your container using option `--net=host`. This way, both containers will have an IP address in your local network.

An example for a container called ubuntu:
`docker run -d --name ubuntu --net=host ubuntu`